# Jquery ajax request done and fail with Axios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request, axios

I have a custom API setup as:

```
export default class API {

  static send(verb, resource, raw_params, callback, errcallback) {

    let org_id = window.localStorage._organization_id,
      params = Object.keys(raw_params).reduce(function(o, k) {
      o[k] = raw_params[k];
      return o;
    }, {});

    errcallback = typeof errcallback === 'function' ? errcallback : function() {};

    if (!!org_id && !params.hasOwnProperty('organization_id')) {
      params.organization_id = org_id;
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: URL + '/' + resource,
      type: verb,
      data: params
      xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
    })
    .done(callback)
    .fail(errcallback);
  }

  static get(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('GET', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }

  static post(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('POST', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }

  static put(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('PUT', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }

  static del(resource, params, callback, errcallback) {
    API.send('DELETE', resource, params, callback, errcallback);
  }
}
```

Then I can make an API request from any file in my application as:

```
API.post('x/y', {params}, res => {
  this.setState(res);
}, (xhr) => {
  const errorMessage = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
  alert('error', 5000, errorMessage);
}
```

I am trying to replace this with `axios` and I replaced the `$.ajax` request with the following:

```
axios({
  method: verb,
  url: `${URL}/${resource}`,
  data: params,
  xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
})
 .then(callback)
 .catch(errcallback)
```

But it doesn't call the response or error callback. Is there a way I can update this class to handle that or do I have to replace every request with an axios request instead and use the axios defined `res` and `xhr`?

Comment: I assume verb is a string you pass to that axios function? such as 'GET', if not it should be the method you desire.

Comment: Yes verb is the GET, POST, PUT, DELETE string. The request does go through and I can see it in the log, the backend rails api does send a response as well

Comment: Could you please clean up your `API` class code? For instance, where is the `send` method? Why is there procedural `jQuery.ajax()` code within the class definition and not within a method?

Comment: @Phil I updated the API class and added all the missing code

Answer (score 1):

Axios by default posts data as `application/json` whereas jQuery defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. See https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format.

Also, while jQuery uses `data` as the query parameters for GET requests, Axios separates request body payloads and query parameters into the `data` and `params` properties, respectively.

With that in mind, to drop-in-replace jQuery with Axios, you would need to do the following...

```js
const request = {
  method: verb,
  url: `${URL}/${resource}`,
  withCredentials: true      //  are you sure you need this?
}
if (verb === 'GET' || verb === 'DELETE') {
  request.params = params // query params, no request body
} else {
  /// set appropriate request content-type
  request.headers = { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

  // convert "params" object into request body string
  request.data = Object.entries(params).reduce((data, [key, value]) => {
    data.append(key, value)
    return data
  }, new URLSearchParams())
}
axios(request).then(callback).catch(errcallback)
```

The `Object.entries(params).reduce(...)` thing is just a simplified example of producing an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` string from a flat object. Axios itself recommends the [qs library](https://github.com/ljharb/qs).

Also keep in mind that [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) is not available in any version of Internet Explorer.